# change text colour in psfrag

Tags: color, psfrag

I'm wondering if one could set final text colour to some rgb in `psfrag`? This:

```
\psfrag{D}[lc][lc][0.85]{\color[rgb]{0, 110, 180}{Deuterium}}
```

is not working.

Thanks!

Comment: We probably need a full minimal example please. For example have you loaded a package that supports `\color`?

Comment: it ought to work but safer would be `\textcolor`

Answer (score 1):

Your example produces the error

```
! Package color Error: Argument ` 110' not in range [0,1].
```

the `rgb` model takes values in the range 0-1 you seem to be looking for RGB which takes integers in 0-255 range.

d.eps

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 50 50
/Times-Roman findfont 10 scalefont setfont
10 10 moveto
(D) show
10 30 moveto
(E) show
showpage
```

tex including the EPS unchanged and then again with `psfrag`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,psfrag}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{d.eps}

\psfrag{D}[lc][lc][0.85]{\color[RGB]{0, 110, 180}{Deuterium}}
\includegraphics{d.eps}

\end{document}
```

[image]